# Testing events and document content in karma-jasmine unit-testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, events, karma-jasmine

I want to test the following functions using jasmine-karma unit testing but I can't find a way to do so.

function One:

```
$scope.info = function(text){
  $(":root").find("#info").remove();
  var htmlObject = "<div id='info' info-alert text='"+$sanitize(text)+"'/>";
  var comments = $compile( htmlObject )( $scope );
  $(document.body).append( comments );
};
```

function 2:

```
 $scope.$on('settingsChanged',function(){
  $scope.getSettings();
});
```

I have tried reading the documentation on how to test events and play with the tests but nothing seems to work.
This is my last attempt for the first but the last line is not the right way of doing it I suppose:

```
 it('info', function() {
        var text="Some information";
        var controller=createController();
        scope.info(text);
        expect($(document.body).val()).toContain(text);  
    });
```

I tried for the second one something similar but nothing seems to work

Comment: Where's your test?  Why didn't this work out?  What error messages did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your text might have been altered by `$sanitize(text)`

AngularJS official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) states that: 
- `$sanitizeProvider`
- service in module ngSanitize
Sanitizes an html string by stripping all potentially dangerous tokens.

So please check if document.body contains your text, and that it has not been altered by $sanitize(text)